# PyQt and OpenCV interfering

Tags: python, pyqt, fbs

I try to make a PyQT application but when I try to make a desktop app out of it I get this error message:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/seansdahl/SpaceNewsApp/target/SpaceNews.app/Contents/MacOS/cv2/cv2.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: __ZN10QByteArray11shared_nullE
  Referenced from: /Users/seansdahl/SpaceNewsApp/target/SpaceNews.app/Contents/MacOS/cv2/../QtTest
  Expected in: /Users/seansdahl/SpaceNewsApp/target/SpaceNews.app/Contents/MacOS/PyQt5/../QtCore
```

I use the following two imports:

```
import cv2
import qtpy
```

but I have the PyQt5 module installed as well.
It seems like these two modules are interfering somehow. (The app works as long as I don't import opencv).

What am I missing?

Comment: I recommend creating a virtualenv where you install only the necessary packages and avoid interference. :-)

Comment: But I need both PyQt and OpenCV...

Answer (score 0):

installed pyqt and qtpy may lead to qt confusion.
maybe u can remove them and re-install

Comment: yes, u said the right thing. My answer should be 'remove pyqt and re-install it  '.Thx for pointing out my mistake. BTW , qtpy can be install seperately by using 'pip install qtpy',it provides abstraction layer on pyqt5,pyqt4 or pyside.